# if $x^3 + px^2+qx+r = 0$ has three real roots, show that $p^2 \ge 3q$

Tags: calculus, roots, cubics

If $x^3 + px^2+qx+r = 0$ has three real roots, show that $p^2 \ge 3q$

Can I get help on this problem,
thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393869/conditions-for-distinct-real-roots-of-cubic-polynomials

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The existence of $3$ real roots of $P(x)=x^3+px^2+qx+r$ implies the existence of how many real roots of $P'(x)=3x^2+2px+q$?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative hint: Express $p$ and $q$ in terms of the roots using Vieta's relations and see what transpires.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x^3 + px^2 +qx+r$ 
$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2px +q$ 
Since $\operatorname{discr}{f(x)} > 0$ 
Therefore $\operatorname{discr}{f'(x)} > 0$ 
Thus 
$\Rightarrow 4p^2 - 12q > 0$ 
$\Rightarrow p^2 > 3q$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are you sure the O.P. knows about the discriminant of a *cubic* polynomial? Especially with a term in $x^2$?