# Collinear Points on a Curve

Tags: derivatives, curves, algebraic-curves

I encountered a problem recently wherein I had to find the value of the coefficient of the second degree term  in a 4th degree equation (other coefficients were given) such that there are $4$ collinear points on the curve.
I found a similar question in a problem set wherein the solution included taking the second derivative and solving for the discriminant to be greater than $0$ and obtain an inequality which was the solution but I can't seem to figure out why this works. Please help.

The curve given in the question was $$y=x^4+9x^3+ax^2+2008x+2050$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a monic polynomial $P(x) \in \Bbb{R}[x]$ of degree $4$. Pick two points $(a,P(a)),(a+c,P(a)+d)$ on the curve $P(x)-y=0$, let $$h(t) =P(a+tc) - (P(a)+td) = c^4 t(t-1) (t^2+ft+g) $$

$g = (\frac{h'(0)}{c^4}=-\frac{c P'(a)-d}{c^4}$, $\frac{h(2)}{c^4} = 8+4f+2g, f= \frac{\frac{h(2)}{c^4}-8-2g}{4}$

Iff $f^2-4g>0$ then $t^2+ft+g = (t-u)(t-v)$ has two real roots so $h$ has 4 real roots and $(a+uc,P(a+uc)),(a+vc),P(a+vc))$ are two more points of the curve on the line $(a+tc,P(a)+td)$

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

One sufficient condition would be that there exists 2 local minima at $x_1$ and $x_3$ and a local maxima at $x_2$ such that 
$$x_1<x_2<x_3$$
$$f(x_1), f(x_2) < f(x_3)$$
Since $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$, we can guarente a line will intersect $f$ at 4 points above $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_3)$ and below $f(x_2)$. I.e. there are 3 "humps". This means that 
$$f'(x_1) = f'(x_2) = f'(x_3) = 0 $$
and 
$$f''(x_1), f''(x_3)>0 \text{ and } f''(x_2) < 0$$
Take $a = -1000$, then 
$$f'(x) = 4 (-18.6353 + x) (-1.02017 + x) (26.4055 + x)$$
$$f''(x) = 12 (-166.667 + 4.50002 x + x^2)$$
a quick check shows that the above properties are satisfied for 
$$x_1 = -26.4055, \  x_2 = 1.02017, \ x_3 = 18.6353$$
see this [plot of f(x)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B9x%5E3-%201000x%5E2%2B2008x%2B2050)

Comment: I don't get how you took a to be -1000. Here I have to find what a is not the maximas and minimas. Please explain furthermore

Comment: After differentiating I know that $2a + 2008 \approx 0$ in order to have 3 roots of the derivative. Otherwise the constant term would dominate and we would only get one from the cubic derivative. Then I used Wolfram to factor it.

Comment: So what is the final answer according to you? The answer key provides a range for 'a'

Comment: Also in the 2nd inequality it should be f(x3)<f(x2)

Comment: My trial and error method does not provide a range. The question you asked seemed to only want some $a$. You would have to consider when $f'$ has 3 roots. So this post might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393869/conditions-for-distinct-real-roots-of-cubic-polynomials

Comment: Okk got it. Btw the method which I have written in the question do you have any idea why it works?

Comment: @Dayton $f'$ doesn't necessarily need to have $3$ real roots.